# htmlのinput formのsubmitが無反応な場合の可能性

Tags: html

曖昧な質問で申し訳ありませんが、
サイトで設けているinput formが、submitしても送信されないとユーザーから問い合わせを受けました。

formは複数のtextと一つのfileで構成されており
submitにonclickで空白チェックをし空白はalertの上、falseにしています。
fileはmaxfileupload周りを120Mまで上げています。通常画像をアップするフォームなのでイタズラでもなければ引っかかると思えません。
次のページではmysql保存です。

analyticsを見るに、おそらくandroidのchromeと思われ、しかし、プライバシーがどうのと言われても困るので相手に確認してないのですが、
手元のアンドロイドで確認しても、alertも出るし次のページへも進みます。

念のためios、pcでも試しましたが通ります。

また、javascriptのオンオフに関しては、javascriptオフの場合は別ページにジャンプさせるので、オフではないと思われます

このようなフォームでsubmitが無反応な場合、
ブラウザでalertを無効化しているか、
アップロードが遅すぎる、以外に何か可能性はあるでしょうか

Comment: そのユーザーに協力していただき解決方法を探るべきです。動作環境(OSやブラウザの種類)、どのように操作したか、現象は再現するか、画面にメッセージは表示されたか、その場合はスクリーンショットを送っていただくとか、アクセスログを記録しているなら、ユーザーが操作した直後に連絡していただき、ログを確認するなど。

Comment: javascriptのエラーをキャッチして、エラーが出ていないか、確認してみるといいかもしれません。読み込みのタイミングなどによって、フォームの初期化スクリプトがエラーで転けて、その後のスクリプトが全部失敗していたという経験があります。